# Mediawiki create a template for external linking

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

Some mediawikis are using a template or something like that to create twitter links in articles without the external link icon.

For instance in http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Mojang_AB each employee has a twitter link, this is not just an external link to twitter.com, but like [twitter:notch|@notch] in the source.

Does anyone know how I can add this feature to my mediawiki?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those links are called [Interwiki links](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aInterwiki) and you can add them to your wiki by inserting into the `interwiki` table.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the external link icon, you can wrap the link in `<span class="plainlinks">`, like this:

```
 <span class="plainlinks">http://stackoverflow.com/</span>
```

or even

```
 <span class="plainlinks">[http://stackoverflow.com Stack Overflow]</span>
```

A template for creating links to Twitter user pages might look something like this:

```
<includeonly><span class="plainlinks twitterlink">[https://twitter.com/{{{1}}} @{{{1}}}]</span></includeonly>
```

or, with the extension StringFunctions installed (to allow for input both with and without the @ sign):

```
<includeonly><span class="plainlinks twitterlink">[https://twitter.com/{{#replace:{{{1}}}|@|}} @{{#replace:{{{1}}}|@|}}]</span></includeonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find these sites interesting:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Twitter4wiki

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TwitterFeed